# How do you get a li to delete itself if it contains an element of a certain class inside of it?

Tags: jquery

Right now I'm trying to delete all `li` items that contain a certain class, `classname`

```
if ( $('li .classname').length > 0 ){
    alert('Yeah im here');
    $(this).remove();
}
```

I've got the alert coming up which seems to be verifying that I'm checking for it correctly. Where do I go from here, though, to make it delete itself? And if there's a better way please let me know.

HTML...

```
<li>
  <div class="classname">
  Hi
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: why don't you use $.each

Comment: Do you have tried the [parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) method? Use it like this line `$('li .test').parent().remove();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**:has()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) selector

```js
$('li:has(.classname)').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>No classname</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="classname">Has classname</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>No classname</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="classname">Has classname</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method, inside this method, you can use `this` as the selector to point to `.classname` element.

Then, using [parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) method to get the `li` tag for deleting

```js
$('li .classname').each(function () {
  alert('Yeah im here');
  
  // point to <li> item that contains this element
  var li = $(this).parent();
  
  // remove parent 
  li.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>Hi</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="classname">Hi</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Hi</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why do you use a `each()` loop with a bad performance when you can just use `parent()` like this example `$('li .classname').parent().remove();` ?

Comment: @UfguFugullu It's useful when you want to do something with that element before deleting. In this case, throwing an alert